# Simulate/emulate Google TPU for development and debug

Tags: tpu

Is there an emulator to debug code for TPU, instead of expending money debugging on real TPU before everything is ready to work?

Any other technique that would have a similar effect would be appreciated as answer as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out that **there's not** an emulator nor any kind of virtualization of TPUs for development.

What can be done **instead**, is to run your code in [Colab notebooks](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/colabs), being restricted by some limitations (i.e. your data has to be stored in Google Cloud to be accessible for the notebook).

There are several articles in websites like Medium about training/using models in TPUs through notebooks, each one focusing on different aspects or with different content within the example code. [Here](https://heartbeat.fritz.ai/step-by-step-use-of-google-colab-free-tpu-75f8629492b3) is one of them, just to provide an example and further useful links for anyone interested.